# D3 table with rowspan

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm repetitively new to D3, but have hit a dead end trying to use D3 to convert this:

```
[
 { Year: 2014, Month: 'Dec', Team: 'T1', Sales: 123 },
 { Year: 2015, Month: 'Jan', Team: 'T1', Sales: 123 },
 { Year: 2015, Month: 'Jan', Team: 'T2"', Sales: 123 },
 { Year: 2015, Month: 'Feb', Team: 'T1', Sales: 123 },
 { Year: 2015, Month: 'Feb', Team: 'T2"', Sales: 123 },
 { Year: 2015, Month: 'Apr', Team: 'T1', Sales: 123 },
 { Year: 2015, Month: 'Apr', Team: 'T2"', Sales: 123 },
 { Year: 2015, Month: 'Mar', Team: 'T1', Sales: 123 },
 { Year: 2015, Month: 'Mar', Team: 'T2"', Sales: 123 }
]
```

into this:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>Month</td>
        <td>T1</td>
        <td>T2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">2015</td>
        <td>Dec</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">2015</td>
        <td>Jan</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Feb</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apr</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mar</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible?  I have tried pre-processing the data with nest to restructure it but still have been unable to get my desired table output.

Any tips or pointers much appresiated

Comment: You need [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used d3 to first convert all your data into a nested format based on year:

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
    return d.Year;
}).entries(data);
```

Then created the table tr td like this:

```
nested_data.forEach(function (d) {
    var rowspan = d.values.length;
    d.values.forEach(function (val, index) {
        var tr = thead.append("tr");
        if (index == 0) { //rowspan only for first element
            tr.append("td")
                .attr("rowspan", rowspan)
                .text(val.Year);
        }
        tr.append("td")
            .text(val.Month);
        tr.append("td")
            .text(val.Team);
        tr.append("td")
            .text(val.Sales);

    });
});
```

Full working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/Ldw8m3zy/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much.  This really helps!

Comment: This code does work and is helpful however it does not feel like the d3 way to do this; it does not bind the datums to the dom elements, simply prints them out. This will become a problem later if you want to handle a click event or other situation where you want d3 to track the data binding. I will add an answer with my solution for anyone else who had my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to do this exact thing but needed the ability to keep the d3 data bindings so I could access the data on click events.

By allowing d3 to bind the data via the `selection.data(...)` function the d3 keeps track of what dom elements belong to what datums. The code is essentially the same as @cyril and indeed does use a for each loop to create the elements; however, it is all done with d3 calls vs plain javascript loops that create a static display.

Another difference is that I group the parent collection of the whole year each into its own tbody element in the table.

Working example on [JSBin](http://jsfiddle.net/duhkota/259cnp2j/).

```
var table = d3.select("body").append("table"),
  thead = table.append("thead");

thead.append("tr")
  .selectAll("th")
  .data(["Year", "Month", "T1", "Sales"])
  .enter()
  .append("th")
  .text(function(column) {
    return column;
  });

//this will group my data into key:year and all its yearly data
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Year;
  }).entries(data);

var rowgroups = table.selectAll('tbody')
  .data(nested_data)
  .enter()
  .append('tbody')
  .each(function(rowgroup) {
    var rowspan = rowgroup.values.length;
    // Add the actual table rows nested in a tbody for this group of year
    d3.select(this)
      .selectAll('tr')
      .data(function(d) {
        return d.values;
      })
      .enter().append('tr')
      .each(function(rowdata, index) {
        var row = d3.select(this);
        if (index == 0) {
          row.append('td').attr('rowspan', rowspan).text(rowdata.Year);
        }
        row.append('td').text(rowdata.Month);
        row.append('td').text(rowdata.Team);
        row.append('td').text(rowdata.Sales);

        // Add a click handler that will return the datum instead of undefined
        row.on('click', function(rowdata) {
          console.log('Row Clicked');
          console.log(rowdata);
        });
      });
  });
```

*I am new to d3 and would love feedback on this solution, it does work just not sure if this is the best way to do it.*